# Issues with a Counter that is tallying term appearances

Tags: list-manipulation, text

I am working with an array of textfiles, trying to see how frequent certain terms are. However, I am running into some difficulty with my running counts of bigram frequency. Here is a snippet of my code that has been giving me trouble:

```
SetDirectory[
  "/users/ianmilligan/desktop/project/blah/blah/"];

filelist = FileNames["*bigrams.txt"];
citizenCounter97 = {};

Do[
  citizenchecker97 = Get[file];
  Clear[bigramHash];
  (bigramHash[Sequence @@ #1] = #2) & @@@ citizenchecker97;
  count = bigramHash["ottawa", "citizen"];
  Print[ToString[file] <> ":" <> ToString[count]];
  AppendTo[citizenCounter97, count];
  , {file, filelist}];
```

The file that is being checked looks like this `citizenchecker97`=

```
  {{{"owner", "further"}, 262}, {{"on", "the"}, 206}, {{"the", 
  "women"}, 204}, {{"women", "s"}, 197}, {{"maritime", 
  "baptist"}, 195}, {{"and", "the"}, 193}, {{"for", 
  "the"}, 189}, {{"the", "maritime"}, 186}, {{"by", 
  "the"}, 180}, {{"with", "the"}, 170}, {{"the", 
  "missionaries"}, 146}, {{"that", "the"}, 142}, {{"the", 
  "mission"}, 141}...}}
```

As it stands, my `bigramHash` (which stems from an [earlier exceptionally helpful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629311/extracting-frequency-data-from-sorted-list-of-phrases)) generates a number if the file contains that bigram (if it appears twice, it generates '2', which I want to `AppendTo` `citizenCounter97`. If it *doesn't* contain the bigram, however, it generates `bigramHash[ottawa, citizen]`.

My plan was to just generate a list, subsequently just `Cases[citizenCounter97,_Integer];` the thing, and have a sense of how often the given term appeared.

Problem is, the results did not make sense. When I went in and started de-bugging, I realized that the counts that come out of `Print` were completley different than the lists it was generating! The result for `citizenCounter97` would be like this:

```
{2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
 bigramHash["ottawa", "citizen"], bigramHash["ottawa", "citizen"], 
 bigramHash["ottawa", "citizen"]}
```

Whereas the real `Print` output would show that the first 12 results were nothing, the 13th was 2, and then nothing again until 27, when it became 1.

So basically, I am confused as to what's happening, why my counter is completely divergent from the reality as I do it manually/debug with `Print`.

Thanks in advance, and happy to clarify as best I can.

**---- edited to add ----**

I suspect one solution lies in an `If` statement - i.e. `If` count is an integer, then append that; if the 'If' ends up being not an integer, then return 0. I've tried a variety of calls using `Head` however, and am still hitting a brick wall.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are wanting and what the file `citizenchecker97` contains. Could you describe what you want as a black box, i.e. what goes in and what do you hope to come out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am following your code, I think the problem is that you are collecting expressions such as `bigramHash["ottawa", "citizen"]` which will evaluate differently depending on the `DownValue` associated with `bigramHash`.  Therefore, these expression will evaluate to whatever the final DownValue of `bigramHash["ottawa", "citizen"]` is, if present.

Here is a simplified example of the problem:

```
filelist = {
   {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}},
   {{"cat", 5}, {"dog", 3}},
   {{"a", 4}, {"b", 6}}
 };

Reap[Do[
   Clear[bigramHash];
   (bigramHash[#] = #2) & @@@ file;
   count = bigramHash["a"];
   Print[count];
   Sow[count],
   {file, filelist}
]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[26]:= 1
>
> During evaluation of In[26]:= bigramHash[a]
>
> During evaluation of In[26]:= 4
>
> {1, 4, 4}
> ```

One simple fix is to define a default DownValue e.g. `bigramHash[___] = 0`:

```
Reap[Do[
   Clear[bigramHash];
   bigramHash[___] = 0;
   (bigramHash[#] = #2) & @@@ file;
   count = bigramHash["a"];
   Print[count];
   Sow[count],
   {file, filelist}
]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[36]:= 1
>
> During evaluation of In[36]:= 0
>
> During evaluation of In[36]:= 4
>
> {1, 0, 4}
> ```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for deciphering my code. The issue laid in not having the right terminology to describe my problem! The `bigramHash[__]=0` addition works swimmingly, and the results look like they should.